# Report Builder - Use one dataset in the where clause of the query for another dataset

Tags: reporting-services, dataset

I'm using SQL Server Report Builder 2014.

DatasetA is created from TableA in DatasourceA and contains a single column of IDs.

DatasetB, on which my report is based, needs to have all rows from TableB in DatasourceB `WHERE TableB.ID IN (DatasetA)`.

I've done lots of Google'ing, but cannot find a solution that works.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For this you could use a hidden parameter in the report, lets call is `ParamA`. Populate `ParamA` using `DatasetA`, set it as a multi-select parameter and set the defaults using `DatasetA` i.e. all items will be selected.

Then in `DatasetB` have `where id in (@ParamA)`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'd actually tried that technique, but must be missing something important.  I think the parameter needs an ampersand though in the where clause i.e. where id in (@ParamA)?  If that's right, when I do that, when I run the query in the Query Designer, I first get prompted for parameter details by a "Define Query Parameters" dialog.  If I simply hit "OK", I get an "unexpected symbol" exception at the "@".  I'm pretty sure the parameter is defied correctly though (Internal, Allow Multiple Values, Available and Default values are my dataset and value field).

Comment: I'm guessing I shouldn't be prompted for when trying to run the query, but am not sure how to guarantee it uses the dataset.

Comment: If its prompting you it means it can't parse the query. Hard to advise further but I can assure you the technique works as I've used it. Maybe a syntax error in the query, maybe an issue with the parameter name/definition?

Comment: Test the query in SSMS with the parameter condition changed to something testable. If thats OK then I sometimes create a new report using the query to get the report builder to generate the dataset and parameters freshly - and then copy any changes across to the real report.

Comment: The query works fine if I use "where id in (12, 33, 54, 77, 91)".   However, when I change it to "where id in (@ParamA)" in Query Designer, when I hit OK, I'm shown a dialog with a "Define Query Parameters" titlebar. It appears to be asking me to define ParamA, even though it's defined as a report parameter that populated by my other dataset query.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but don't know what else to tweak.

Comment: I haven't, but will try that now. Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: I think the issue has turned out to be my DB driver.  I'm connecting to a proprietary datastore with a "SQL-like" interface, and their driver implementation doesn't seem to support the "@" parameter syntax.  I see "Unexpected <symbol>..." at the @ in my WHERE clause.  I'm open to other ideas as to how to meet this requirement.

Comment: Have you looked at this page where it explains connecting to other databases https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/add-data-from-external-data-sources-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: One small step forward today.  The parameter syntax in my dataset query is not "@ParamName", but rather "?" i.e. "where id in (?)".  So it's not a driver limitation with parameters in the query, but rather a different syntax.  However, my "?" parameter needs to represent multiple values, but when I check the "Allow multiple values" checkbox in the parameter definition, I get the following exception back at runtime: "Cannot add multi value query parameter 'ParamA' for dataset 'DataSetA' because it is not supported by the data extension."  So maybe now I've got a driver limitation.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, when you use `where name in (@aa)` in query designer(text mode) and click OK, it will prompt like below

[image]

You could hard code in it, it seems to support single parameter to test in designer, but when you preview it in report, you could pass multiple parameters. You could click OK to ignore it or pass hard code in it to see whether parameters could work or not.

In addition, if you want to show dataset A's value in parameter list, you could set available value in parameter properties (get values from query)